# How to remove label from sink without damaging the sink?

Tags: bathroom

[image]

Can a label like this be removed without damaging the porcelain? Should I use a razor? Can it even be removed without damaging the sink?

This thing is over a millimeter thick. I think it's plastic.

Comment: Have you tried a little heat from even a hair dryer or boiling water to see if it loosens at all?

Comment: No. That's a good idea. I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning.

Comment: Well, I started to use a blow-dryer, but I was paranoid about the thermal cracking warning, so I didn't heat it up too much and just started tugging at it / pushing it with my fingers until an edge started to lift.  Then I got my finger nail under it and started tugging until it slowly pulled off. In fact, there was no residue left behind. Not sure whether to select an answer, since I didn't technically/fully do what was suggested. Should I select the heat one?

Comment: [This](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/273561/23295), except it's a 20yo 1" putty knife "ground to a nub" with no corners left, instead of an inflexible 5-in-1.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get under an edge of that label, try sawing it off with some dental floss. You'll still have a stick residue to deal with, but there are products that can remove that without leaving a mess.

Comment: That's a good idea, but all the edges are flush.

Comment: Are you saying that the emblem is recessed?

Answer (score 1):

Razorblades can be dicy with porcelain - it's possible to scrape metal off into the ceramic surface and leave a mark that's difficult or impossible to get out.

I'd start with heat - somewhat gently (no thermal cracking, please) such as a hair dryer, and either a plastic puttyknife (if you want to buy a tool) or sanding an edge on an out-of-date credit card (if you'd rather not buy something you can make) to pry the label up once you get the adhesive warm. Depending on the adhesive, heat may make it release very easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "no thermal cracking, please"? Do you mean, "Don't heat it up too much"? If so, how would I know how much heat to apply? Like, just push at it every so often until it starts to move?

Comment: Don't use a torch/flame, or pour boiling water on it without first pouring warm and then hot water on it, or use a heat gun rather than a hairdryer - minimize thermal shock/stress while managing to get the label warm. And yes, keep checking it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a bathroom sink from American Standard and it came with the exact same sticker.  It came off without a problem using my fingernail.  It came off super clean and easy!