# Best solution for cutting out mortar bedding?

Tags: tile, patio, landscaping, mortar

I have been putting down porcelain tiles and I noticed one was slighly loose so I manageed to lift it up so that I can put new mortar down, slurry on the tile and place it back down.

Question is what is the best solutution for removing the mortar bed from the ground? I thought about a chisel but I was thinking of using an angle grinder to cut it and lift it out. Does this sounds about right?

Thanks

Comment: What's your substrate?

Comment: The tile is on compressed limestone with about 4cm mortar bed. Just dont' want to damage the tile bed for the nearby tiles if i start hitting the mortar bed with a chisel i.e vibrations. It might actually not do anything to the adjacent tiles but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Your metal implement coming into contact with the tile in any way shape or form is the concern. As you approach the edges of the adjoining tile you work laterally to them only, so that the impact isn't directed at them or their mortar bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a dull chisel is too sharp.

You want your crappy **5-in-1** that's almost ground to a nub because that's the one you do that with and it doesn't bite into the subfloor anymore. The harder it is, the higher the angle needs to be to keep it from slipping past your working line when you hit the **full metal tang** with a hammer. If it's hard AF, you have to have it at almost 90 degrees to chip it away. The softer it is, the lower to the floor you can angle it, and it just scrapes off with each tap.

Having to break out the grinder to do a single tile is a bad day. If it's relatively new thinset, scraping it shouldn't be a problem. For cleaning the back of the tile, maybe....

Comment: To start the working line, you have it almost straight up. Then keep tapping as you lower the angle as far as possible, that you get at least a few taps in before it slips past. If it keeps slipping, start over and don't go so low. If you can get it to start chipping 1/16 of an inch at a time and you can see subfloor; that's what we want. Don't get discouraged or become overzealous leaving some behind but achieving big chunks that make you feel good about the process. As soon as you see clean subfloor, ease the angle just a little bit.